# Showing a lot of picturebox in a form and playing gif, causes the form and gifs to freeze

Tags: c#, gif, picturebox

I try to write an application with a large number of GIF animations in a form (30-40 picture boxes and each .gif image is 200-500kb). However, when I use so much Picturebox and run the program, the form freezes too much, and the gif animations that normally need to pass to the next image in 100MS, move to the next image within 5-6 seconds. How to handle this situation. Thank you

I tried to show pictures ,in gif, one by one that way but i had same result

```
 public class Class1 : PictureBox
    {
   
        public Class1()
        {
       
      
        }

     
       
        public Image[] imagelist { get; set; } = new Image[10];
    
        public int currentimage;
        private int imagecount = 1;

        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();
            this.Image = imagelist[0];
            imagecount = imagelist.TakeWhile(r => r != null).Count();
        }

        public void NextImage()
        {
            currentimage = (currentimage + 1) % imagecount;
            this.Image = imagelist[currentimage];
        }
    }



public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            array = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(f => f.GetValue(this) != null&&f.FieldType == typeof(Class1)).Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).Cast<Class1>().ToArray();
            Thread = new Thread(Start);
            Thread.Start();
        }

        private Thread Thread;
        private void Start()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(400);
            while (true)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
               {
                   foreach (Class1 class1 in array)
                   {
                       class1.NextImage();
                   }
               }));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
```

Comment: 40 pboxes should not be a big issue. How large are the images in pixels!?

Comment: I have just tried it with a .gif animation of 57 kb and 140x114 pixels and in some pictureboxes it took 5-6 seconds for the animation to start. how can i optimize this?

Comment: To create an animation, if that is what you want, I would do away with Thread and go for a Timer, which is meant to do just that..

Comment: Actually i tried it just to fix the situation (putting the images,contained in the gif file, one by one into the picturebox) but it didn't work. When I set gifs from resources to the picturebox normally (this was the first method I tried), I still experience freezing. i have just tried to change pictureboxes' sizemode from strechimage to normal and got a better result. But this way is too hard for me. Should i resize all  animations to the rigth size and use sizemode normal?

Comment: Hm, not sure but that may be a good idea. Gif treatment has somewhat changed over the years and it used to play only one at a time some years ago.

Comment: Thank you. So, is there any performance difference between addinggif images to the resource then adding them to the picturebox and using the Image.FromFile function?

Comment: Not liekley and nothing that would last..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'BeginInvoke' instead 'Invoke'. Invoke makes your ui wait until action finished and it will make your app not responding or slow. Use 'BeginInvoke' often in windows apps.

or

I think it's because your pictures has different size than your picturebox or has different w/h ratio from picturebox so it had to calculate the streching and takes time. So you can do

- if your picturebox has const width and height, resize your image or gif with same size with picturebox
- or change to normal and not do any change on picturebox sizemode

Comment: I still have the same problem, only when I set the sizemode from strechimage to normal I get a good result. Could this be the cause of my optimization problem? if so what solution should i try?

Comment: @EnesSez I edited my answer I hope it's help